# Configure debian server host for ipv6

Tags: debian, ipv6, nameservers

I nee my website to be accessible though ipv6 network, I used [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6) (IPv6 6to4 Configuration) and got some results but my website is still not reachable in ipv6.

I tested my domain (creforma.fr) on several websites:

http://ipv6-test.com

> AAAA DNS record       fe80::207:cbff:fe03:aee9
>   IPv6 web server         web server is unreachable : Invalid argument

http://ready.chair6.net

```
-DNS (IPv6 NS)
PASS
Hostname creforma.fr does have IPv6-addressed nameservers defined.
-DNS (IPv6 TLD NS)
PASS
Hostname top-level domain (fr.) does have IPv6-addressed nameservers defined.
-DNS (IPv4 A Record)
PASS
Hostname creforma.fr does have an IPv4 A record (163.172.29.247).
-DNS (IPv6 AAAA Record)
PASS
Hostname creforma.fr does have an IPv6 AAAA record (fe80::207:cbff:fe03:aee9).
-DNS (MX Record)
FAIL
Hostname creforma.fr does not have an MX with an AAAA record.
-DNS (Glue)
PASS
Glue does not appear to be needed; nameserver configuration for creforma.fr is not self-referencing.
-IPv4 Connectivity
PASS
Successfully connected to creforma.fr on port 80 over IPv4.
-IPv6 Connectivity
FAIL
Could not connect to creforma.fr on port 80 over IPv6.
-IPv4 Literals
PASS
Did not locate any IPv4 literals within HTML content.
```

I don't know how to find the problem or how to configure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a Link-Local address for DNS in either IPv4 or IPv6. All IPv6 interfaces use the same Link-Local network (`fe80::/10`), so you must use a scope (interface identifier, which is local to a host) on the end of the Link-Local address, e.g. `%eth1`, and these addresses are not routable.

The address you have,`fe80::207:cbff:fe03:aee9`, is meaningless because it could exist on a link to any interface from an IPv6 host, and there is no scope to identify the particular interface the host should use.

Also, I have never seen any web application which can use a Link-Local address.

You will need to use a Global IPv6 address if you want to use IPv6 contact sites on the public Internet, e.g. http://ipv6-test.com.